# WP in subdirectory: how to show items on non-wp in root

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress is installed in the subdirectory «/blog», and is accessible there.
I’m trying to find out how to place the last blog-item as the main article in the non-wp root «index.php».

All I can find is about WP in subdirectory, and acting if it is in the root, but that's not what I want. The blog *must* stay in the subdirectory, because the rest of the site is non-WP. I know it is possible; I read about it years ago, but I can't find that source anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In root-index add:
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');

And then where you want to post your post:

```
<article>
<?php
    $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');

    foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <? 
    php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>    
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 

    <?php endforeach;?>

</article>
```

That's all...
Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website